# My php file is not working

Tags: php, session

I have done a basic session script, it is supposed to create session variable when a user posts his username, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

Can anybody tell me What is wrong with this script?

Comment: Because your script is a bit lower the 'basic', you forgot to start the session before you use it! (`session_start();`)

Comment: You need to add `session_start();` at the beginning of the file where you want to use the session.

Comment: Please go through the basics: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Did you read the manual ^ --- ? All of the answers given so far, are correct; pick one to close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `session_start();`. It sets up a key with value in your browser.

You need to  call it every time you want to access the `$_SESSION` [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Example:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user_name'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

?>
```

Using `session_start();` at the beginning of your file and every file using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You should session_start().
It sets up a cookie in your browser.
You should call it every request when you want to access (read from or write to) a $_SESSION['variable'];

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user_name'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user_name'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

?>
```